# Output returned of a method as an input for another method in Java?

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that presents a menu to the user with four choices, namely entering a string, displaying it with spaces removed, displaying it backward, and quitting. How can I pass the string input from the EnterString method to the NoSpaces method and DisplayBackward method?

I tried follows:

```
public class StringMenu
{
    public static String stringinput;
    public static String s;

    public String EnterString() {
        System.out.print("Input a string: ");
        Scanner newstring = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stringinput = newstring.nextLine();
        return stringinput;
    }

    public void setstring(String stringinput){
        this.stringinput = stringinput;
    }

    public static void editString(String s){
        s.setstring(stringinput);
    }

    public String NoSpaces() {
        String stringinput2 = " ";
        editString(stringinput2);
        String enterfirst = "Enter a string first";
        if(stringinput2 != null){
            char[] Array = stringinput2.toCharArray();
            String nospaces = "";
            for (int n=0; n<Array.length; n++ )
            {
                if ((Array[n] != ' ') && (Array[n] != '\t'))
                    nospaces = nospaces + Array[n];
            }
            System.out.println(nospaces);
            return nospaces;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Enter a string first");
            return enterfirst;
    }

    public void DisplayBackward() {
        String stringinput3 = " ";
        editString(stringinput3);
        if(stringinput3 != null) {
            char[] orig = stringinput3.toCharArray();
            String reverse="";
            int p = orig.length-1;
            for (int n=0; n<=p; p-- )
                reverse = reverse + orig[p];
            System.out.println(reverse);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Enter a string first");
    }

    public static void Quit(){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a dd/MM/yy");  
        Date date = new Date();   
        System.out.println("Your session has ended. The current time is " + (formatter.format(date)));  
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringMenu s = new StringMenu();
    int choice;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("\n============================\n");
        System.out.println("Enter the number of your choice: ");
        System.out.println("(1) Enter a string");
        System.out.println("(2) Display the string with all its spaces removed");
        System.out.println("(3) Display the string backward");
        System.out.println("(4) Quit");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1: 
                s.EnterString();
                break;
            case 2:
                s.NoSpaces();
                break;
            case 3: 
                s.DisplayBackward();
                break;
            case 4: 
                Quit();
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Enter numbers from 1 to 4 only");
            }
        }
        while (choice!=4);
    }
```

If option 1 was chosen - with `'hello world`' as the input - then 2 was picked `'hello world'` should be displayed; if 3 was chosen afterwards `'dlrow olleh'` should be displayed.

An error message appears for line 21 saying that it cannot find the symbol method `setstring(String)` with a location of variable s of type String.

Comment: Full of syntax errors, Where is Quit function

Comment: You need a tutorial and teacher on programming basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your program run as expected with all modifications.
Tested in IntellijIdea.

```
public class StringMenu {

    private static String stringInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringMenu s = new StringMenu();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        do {
            System.out.print("\n============================\n");
            System.out.println("Enter the number of your choice: ");
            System.out.println("(1) Enter a string");
            System.out.println("(2) Display the string with all its spaces removed");
            System.out.println("(3) Display the string backward");
            System.out.println("(4) Quit");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("You enter String -> " + s.enterString());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("string after Remove space -> " + s.noSpaces(stringInput));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Backward string -> " + s.displayBackward(stringInput));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    s.Quit();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter numbers from 1 to 4 only");
            }
        } while (choice != 4);
    }

    public String enterString() {
        System.out.print("Input a string: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        return stringInput = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public String noSpaces(String stringInput) {
        if (stringInput == null) {
            stringInput = enterString();
        }
        char[] stringArray = stringInput.toCharArray();
        String noSpaces = "";
        for (int n = 0; n < stringArray.length; n++) {
            if ((stringArray[n] != ' ') && (stringArray[n] != '\t')) {
                noSpaces = noSpaces + stringArray[n];
            }
        }
        return noSpaces;
    }

    public String displayBackward(String stringInput) {
        String stringBackward = "";
        if (stringInput == null) {
            stringInput = enterString();
        }
        System.out.println("Original string ==>> " + stringInput);
        char[] charArray = stringInput.toCharArray();
        for (int i = charArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            stringBackward = stringBackward + charArray[i];
        }
        return stringBackward;
    }

    public void Quit() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a dd/MM/yy");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Your session has ended. The current time is " + (formatter.format(date)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If line 21 points to

```
public static void editString(String s){
    s.setstring(stringinput);
}
```

, the error message is very obviously. The argument is String type and String does not have setstring method.

If you want to invoke setstring, the method definition should be as below at least.

```
public static void editString(StringMenu sm) { sm.setstring(stringinput); }
```

Answer (score 1):

just create a variable and set the returned value to the created variable , then pass that variable as the argument of the method you want to pass in, then that value will be accessible in the method you've just passed.